# Is Takbeer necessary for Qaza Farz Namaz

Tags: salat, takbir

AssalamElaikum,

I want to know if Takbeer is necessary for Farz Namaz. I offer my prayers individually sommetimes and offer Takbeer for Farz Namaz but I am not sure about saying Takbeer before Qaza farz. Hence currently I am saying Takbeer before Qaza Farz Namaz also. Is it a sin to say Takbeer before Qaza Farz?

Some body please guide me according Quran, Hadeeth and Sunnah.

May Allah bless Jannat for all Muslims.Ameen.
Zulfi.

Comment: What do you mean by takbeer? You can't start a prayer without saying Allahu akbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Takbeer is the process of saying Allahu **Akbar**. Word كَبِير (kabīr) means **great** from the trilateral root k-b-r. The Arabic word أَكْبَر (ʾakbar) is the elative form (greatest). The opening takbeer is one of the pillars or essential parts of the prayer, without which a person’s prayer is invalid and he has not entered the prayer if he does not say it.

> The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “No
> person’s prayer is complete unless he does wudoo’ as it should be done
> and then says ‘Allaahu akbar.’” Al-Albaani said: It was narrated by
> al-Tabaraani with a saheeh isnaad.  Ibn Qudaamah said: This is the
> view of the majority of scholars, past and present.
>
> Al-Mughni, 2/126; see also al-Majmoo’, 3/175.

Comment: AssalamElaikum, @Riyaz, you mean Iqamah is necessary for Qaza Namaz also. I can't find specific answer in the link you posted but I think that hadith in that post covers the Qaza Namaz also.

Comment: و عليكم السلام والرحمة الله وبركاته, please ignore the iqamah part. I have removed it from the answer